# Корректное описание виртуальных машин в инвентарном файле Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

Добрый день. Я добавил в инвентарный файл (inventory) локальную машину и две виртуальных. Все машины под os Ubuntu 16. Файл имеет следующий вид:

```
[local]
home        ansible_connection=local 
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2

[vmhosts]
k4-test-1:4444  ansible_connection=ssh
k4-test-2:5555  ansible_connection=ssh
```

Далее, я пингую все указанные машинки. Пингуется только моя машина, но не виртуалки. Подскажите пожалуйста, как должно выглядеть правильное описание виртуальных машин?

---

В общем, я сменил тип подключения с NAT на сетевой мост. Со своей машины пингую

inventory файл выглядит теперь так:

```
[local]
home      ansible_connection=local 
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2

[vmhost]
k4-test-1 ansible_ssh_host=10.0.2.15
```

Порт по умолчанию 22, я так думаю что его не надо обозначать в этом файле.

Пробую пингануть все описаные хосты:

```
goliath@host:~/k-ansible$ sudo ansible all -i ~/k-
ansible/inventory -m ping
home | SUCCESS => {
"changed": false, 
"ping": "pong"
}
k4-test-1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false, 
"msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. 
We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable 
SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue", 
"unreachable": true
}
```

Версия python на вируалке 2.7

```
k4-test-1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:\nOpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/home/alexandr/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-10.0.2.15-22-k4-test-1\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving \"10.0.2.15\" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to 10.0.2.15 [10.0.2.15] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Connection established.\r\ndebug3: timeout: 10000 ms remain after connect\r\ndebug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0\r\ndebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2\r\ndebug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2\r\ndebug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Authenticating to 10.0.2.15:22 as 'k4-test-1'\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/root/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:7\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.2.15\r\ndebug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received\r\ndebug2: local client KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org\r\ndebug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256\r\ndebug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 30\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 31\r\ndebug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:iZ9BWYDr/dKa2Qpkdl9XzpCjaXcocGLw+ZM4tCKA2U4\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/root/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:7\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.2.15\r\ndebug1: Host '10.0.2.15' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.\r\ndebug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:7\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 1\r\ndebug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 0\r\ndebug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\r\ndebug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))\r\ndebug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))\r\ndebug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))\r\ndebug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 5\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 7\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received\r\ndebug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 6\r\ndebug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password\r\ndebug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup publickey\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: publickey\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug1: No more authentication methods to try.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если имена `k4-test-1` и `k4-test-2` не резолвятся во внутренней сети, нужно явно указать IP:

```
[vmhosts]
k4-test-1 ansible_ssh_host=10.10.10.10 ansible_port=4444
k4-test-2 ansible_ssh_host=10.20.30.40 ansible_port=5555
```

А `ansible_connection=ssh` можно не указывать, это дефолт.

Подробнее — [в документации](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups).

Для быстрой проверки можно использовать модуль ping из ad-hoc команды:

```
ansible all -i inventory/hosts -m ping                                                                                                                                                            
somehostname | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
...
```

Comment: В любом случае порт указывать нужно через `ansible_port`, а не через двоеточие.

Comment: решил проблему созданием пользователя ansible на своей машине и на удаленных, скопировал с локальной машины ssh-ключ на все остальные машинки, чекнул наличие python2.7 на всех хостах.
Вопрос закрыт. Всем спасибо!